# Bootstrap Version 4.5.3 & Datetimepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

Datetimepicker does not open the calendar with Bootstrap version 4.5.3
my example Here --> https://jsfiddle.net/max1974/o1xehjwt/
change the version and work

If use this cdn not work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If use this cdn work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```